# Linux - Reading File from Sudo - "Permission Denied"

Tags: c++, linux, macos, qt, permission-denied

When performing a recursive directory scan of the drive to generate a hash for each file by running the program executable under `sudo`, I'm discovering 1,000s of files are throwing "Permission Denied" errors.

**My Question: Is this by design, why is sudo unable to read the files?  Is what I'm doing even possible because files might be encrypted or currently in use during the time of the scan?**

When I compile to Mac OSX and perform the same scan under `sudo`, I don't have this issue, just Linux.

```
Distro: 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64    x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

An example of files with permission denied:

```
Can't open file:  "/sys/class/gpio/unexport" 
MSG:  "Permission denied" 
Can't open file:  "/sys/class/gpio/export" 
MSG:  "Permission denied"
```

Sample of permission settings:

```
/sys/class/gpio$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Oct  5 04:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 57 root root    0 Oct  4 11:25 ..
--w-------  1 root root 4096 Oct  5 04:51 export
--w-------  1 root root 4096 Oct  5 04:51 unexport
```

MD5 Function where file reads fail:

```
QByteArray MD5(QString sPath)
{
  QByteArray resultMD5 = NULL;

  QFile* file = new QFile(sPath);

  if(file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
  {
    QCryptographicHash* pHashMD5 = NULL;

    resultMD5 = pHashMD5->hash(file->readAll(),QCryptographicHash::Md5);

    file->close();

    //Clean up pointer
    delete pHashMD5;
    delete file;
  }
  else
  {
      qDebug() << "Can't open file: " << sPath;
      qDebug() << "MSG: " << file->errorString();

      file->close();
      delete file;
  }

 return resultMD5;
}
```

Comment: Files under `/sys/...` are not true files, they don't exist on a HDD. According to those *permissions* not even `root` has read access, they are *write-only* 'files'.

Comment: Do you *really* want to read /sys, /dev etc.? That are not files as in images and music on the hard disk, but other strange things. Quote from elsewhere: `sysfs is a ram-based filesystem. It provides a means to export kernel data structures, their attributes, and the linkages between them to userspace.` and dev is a list of nodes of full hard disks and other devices,

Comment: Yeah *`strange things`*. That's the technical term I was missing! ;o)

Comment: This raises a good point, if these are all "Owner Write-Only" files, it's accurate to assume they are always changing, so the Hash would have to be constantly updating to keep up, which is not Optimal for my purposes.

Comment: It comes from `Unix`philosophy that says [Everything Is A File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file), even if it's not a file.

Comment: Re: "always changing" - files in `/sys` can be truly write-only, and not have anything to read ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is under /sys are not really files.  It's an interface into the kernel.

With regard to the examples you have mentioned, see [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt) for an explanation of what they do.

Given their function, it makes no sense to consider that such "files" could be read.

Comment: Miner_Glitch, Galik and deviantfan's responses have provided a conclusive answer to this question.  Very much appreciated. The confusion was when running against OSX and Linux, and getting mixed results.  I guess OSX handles the permission-denied with more grace as I look into my database on OSX, several record entries with empty string hashes, and no permission messages in my logs.